# Prove/Disprove the convergence of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Hey guys I would like to get some hint for this series -
I tried some test but couldn't decide if the series converge or diverge -

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty {\frac{e^{\frac{1}{n}}\sin(\frac{1}{n})}{{\sqrt{n}}}}$$

Thanks!

Comment: I got the radius of convergence $2$ so it is definitely converge in $(-2,2)$

Comment: Instead of changing the series you're asking about (especially when there's already an answer), it would be better to post a new question.

Comment: I rolled back the question. You should open a new question if you want to ask about another series.

Comment: What is happening here, question is keeps on changing.

Comment: The actual question was Barak Mi's original question to which RRL gave an answer. Then Barak Mi changed the question and asked for convergence or divergence of a completely new series, to which I and Jack D'Aurizio gave an answer. Then miracle173 rolled it back to the original one. I edited my answer with the series of the second question of Barak Mi.

Comment: Sorry for the mass! I Wanted to ask about the new series in a new page  but  got confused with the other tab and then went for a while. Thanks for everyone who answered the questions.

Comment: I would recommend accepting RRL's answer here, posting the other series as a new question (as you meant to do), then pinging the other two answers here in comments, giving them a link to the new post, so that they can delete their answers here and move them to the new post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $\sin (1/n) \leqslant 1/n$

Note:  this hint was for the OP's original question, which was about the series

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty {\frac{e^{\frac{1}{n}}\sin(\frac{1}{n})}{{\sqrt{n}}}}$$

Comment: Can u please write the full  inequality of the series?

Comment: Do you know when the p series with term $1/n^p$ converges? Also what is an upper bound for $e^{1/n}$?

Comment: yes, for $p > 1$

Comment: Great -- so we have $e^{1/n} \sin(1/n)/\sqrt{n} < e^{1/n} / n^{3/2} < ???$. Now just bound the term $e^{1/n}$ and you can use the comparison test.

Comment: Ok got it :) bounded it by 3 for example , thanks!

Comment: Perfect.  You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

From [Wallis' product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product) we have:
$$ \frac{(2n)!}{n!^2 4^n} = \frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}=\Theta\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right) $$
so the main term of your series behaves like $\frac{x^n}{n^{3/2}}$ and the radius of convergence is one.

From the [generating function of Catalan's numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#First_proof) (or the generalized binomial theorem) you may also check that your "crazy" series is not crazy at all:

> $$ \forall x\in[0,1],\qquad \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}=-x+\int_{0}^{x}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}=\color{red}{-x+\arcsin x}.$$

Comment: Can't I just use the ratio test? well i didn't succeed to calculate it that way, but your answer may seems too long.

Comment: You might want to move this answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1772780/prove-or-disprove-the-convergence-of-a-series (see comments below the OP here for explanation).