# Prove or Disprove the convergence of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let the following series -

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!}{(4^n)(n!)^2(2n+1)}x^{2n+1}
\end{equation}

$$x>0 , x\ne1 $$

Well I tried to prove that for x < 1 this series converge and for x > 1 diverge but seems to get stuck.
I would like to get a detailed explanation about the tests been used for the proof.

Comment: HINT: Use [Stirling’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) to approximate the factorials.

Comment: Actually it's easier to use the ratio test

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$\frac{\displaystyle
\frac{(2n+2)!}{4^{n+1}((n+1)!)^2(2n+3)}x^{2n+3}}
{\displaystyle\frac{(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2(2n+1)}x^{2n+1}} =
\frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)(2n+1)}{4(n+1)^2(2n+3)}x^2 =
\frac{(2n+1)^2}{(2n+2)(2n+3)}x^2\to x^2.
$$

Comment: I have been struggling with the ratio test, which feels like the easiest way to solve this question. can you please write the final term after reduce the fraction?

Answer (score 1):

Note that ${(2n)!\over4^n(n!)^2}$ can be expanded and then grouped in two different ways:

$${(2n)!\over4^n(n!)^2}=\left((2n)(2n-1)\over(2n)(2n) \right)\left((2n-2)(2n-3)\over(2n-2)(2n-2) \right)\cdots\left(4\cdot3\over4\cdot4 \right)\left(2\cdot1\over2\cdot2 \right)$$

and

$${(2n)!\over4^n(n!)^2}={1\over2n}\left((2n)(2n-1)\over(2n)(2n-2) \right)\left((2n-2)(2n-3)\over(2n-2)(2n-4) \right)\cdots\left(4\cdot3\over4\cdot2 \right)\left(2\cdot1\over2 \right)$$

Observing that the numerators in the first grouping are smaller than the denominators, and vice versa for the second grouping, we have

$${1\over2n}\lt{(2n)!\over4^n(n!)^2}\lt1$$

and consequently

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{x^{2n+1}\over2n(2n+1)}
\lt\sum_{n=1}^\infty{(2n)!\over4^n(n!)^2(2n+1)}x^{2n+1}
\lt\sum_{n=1}^\infty{x^{2n+1}\over2n+1}$$

The root test applied to the two bounding series makes it easy to see that the series in question converges when $0\lt x\lt1$ and diverges when $x\gt1$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution using two different tests:

**Case $\mathbf{x < 1}$:** 
In this case, we use the direct comparison test. First, we show

\begin{equation}
\frac{(2n)!}{(4^n)(n!)^2(2n+1)} \leq 1
\end{equation}

for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. For this, we need a version of Stirling's formula (found for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation)):

\begin{equation}
\sqrt{2\pi}n^{n+\frac1{2}}e^{-n} \leq n! \leq en^{n+\frac1{2}}e^{-n}
\end{equation}

With this, we get

\begin{equation}
\frac{(2n)!}{(4^n)(n!)^2(2n+1)} \leq \frac{(2n)!}{(4^n)(n!)^2} \leq \frac{e(2n)^{2n+\frac1{2}}e^{-2n}}{4^n(\sqrt{2\pi}n^{n+\frac1{2}}e^{-n})^2}
\end{equation}

and then, after simplifying,

\begin{equation}
\frac{e(2n)^{2n+\frac1{2}}e^{-2n}}{4^n(\sqrt{2\pi}n^{n+\frac1{2}}e^{-n})^2} = \frac{e}{2\pi\sqrt{2n}} \leq 1
\end{equation}

for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Now, we can look at the coefficients of the series:

\begin{equation}
\frac{(2n)!}{(4^n)(n!)^2(2n+1)}x^{2n+1} \leq x^{2n+1} \leq x^n
\end{equation}

The last inequality holds because $x < 1$. Moreover, the geometric series that is formed by $x^n$ is convergent, and by the direct comparison test we get that our initial series is convergent as well.

**Case $\mathbf{x > 1}$:**
Here, we use the ratio's test. First, we simplify the quotient:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\frac{(2n+2)!(x^{2n+3})}{4^{n+1}((n+1)!)^2(2n+3)}}{\frac{(2n)!x^{2n+1}}{4^n(n!)^2(2n+1)}} = \frac{x^2(2n+2)(2n+1)^2}{4(n+1)^2(2n+3)} = \frac{x^2(2n+1)^2}{(4n^2+10n+6)}
\end{equation}

Now we need to show that, for given $x > 1$, there exists a big $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n > N$ the last quotient is greater or equal to one. We can do this as follows:

\begin{equation}
\frac{x^2(2n+1)^2}{(4n^2+10n+6)} \geq 1 \Leftrightarrow (4x^2-4)n^2 + (4x^2-10)n + (x^2 -6) \geq 0
\end{equation}

Solving this polynomial for zeros in $n$, we get as the greater solution

\begin{equation}
n_0 = \frac{5-2x^2 + \sqrt{1+8x^2}}{4x^2-4} 
\end{equation}

Now, if we take a quick look at the derivative

\begin{equation}
f^\prime(n) = (8x^2-8)n + (4x^2-10)
\end{equation}

we get by using $x > 1$

\begin{equation}
f^\prime(n) \geq 0 \Leftrightarrow n \geq \frac{5-2x^2}{4x^2-4}
\end{equation}

Comparing this with $n_0$, we see that we are positive whenever

\begin{equation}
n > \lceil n_0 \rceil =: N \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{equation}

proving that the quotient is greater or equal than $1$ for almost all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (note that $n_0$ might be negative for large $x$, which simply means that $N = 0$). Hence, by the ratio's test our series is diverging for $x > 1$.

Comment: why \begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!}{(4^n)(n!)^2} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n!)^2} \
\end{equation}

Comment: You're right, I have to apologize, this is not true. I will delete this from my answer and add it as soon as I have a correct solution.

Comment: No problem , waiting for your correction.

Comment: I edited my answer. I hope that it's correct now.